# I accidentally changed Linux Mint's advanced menu icon to something very large. Now I can't change it back

Tags: linux-mint, mate-desktop, menu

I just see large green and white stripes across the panel. I couldn't do anything on that menu, so had to restart my laptop, and before the panel could load, created a new one and delete the old one. I don't like the other two mint menus. Is there any way I can revert the icon of the "Advanced mintmenu" to its orignal one?

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary fix, you can just change it to any 22x22 or 24x24 icon, something around that range.